# WP7, Local Database, Cast Exception on DateTime Column

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I am trying to store data with a DateStamp in a local database on WP7. I have followed the [MSDN Guidance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/08/01/windows-phone-7-using-local-database-for-application.aspx) and created below code:

```
[Table]
public class HistoricGame
{
    [Column(IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string GameId { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int Score { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int LongestSequence { get; set; }

}

public class HistoricGameContext : DataContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/NumbersNerdDB.sdf";

    public HistoricGameContext()
        :base(ConnectionString)
    {}

    public Table<HistoricGame> HistoricGames
    {
        get { return GetTable<HistoricGame>(); }
    }
}
```

This is called to write to the database in:

```
private void StoreThisGame()
{
    using (var db = new HistoricGameContext())
    {
        if (!db.DatabaseExists())
            db.CreateDatabase();
        var game = new HistoricGame
        {
             DateStamp = DateTime.Now,
             GameId = "1",
             LongestSequence = _currentGame.LongestCorrectSequence,
             Score = _currentGame.TotalPoints
        };
        db.HistoricGames.InsertOnSubmit(game);
        db.SubmitChanges(); //<- This is where it throws an InvalidCastException
    }            
}
```

However  `db.SubmitChanges();` keeps throwing an `InvalidCastException` with the message "Could not convert from type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

I cannot find anything that points me to a database related problem and whilst the original example I used does not include a DateTime, the example on [Silverlightshow.net](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7.1-Local-SQL-Database.aspx) does use a DateTime in a very similar context.

Am I looking at the wrong place or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Annoyingly, I have now tested it on my phone and it appears to be working just fine. Not satisfying though as I won't have any beta testers and cannot necessarily assume it will work on other phone it it isn't even working on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

In my case it was missing the value on the property "Server Data Type" of my table. I had the property "Type" defined as DateTime though, but it was not enough.